# TextBoxFor setting name of property incorrectly and in turn not binding the model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, post, model-binding

In one of my strongly typed Views, of type `ProfileModel`, I invoke an editor for another type:

```
@model MVC3App.WebUI.Models.ProfileModel

<div class="contact-form">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ContactModel)
</div>
```

I have this simple model:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email:")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Message:")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I use in my EditorTemplate view for `ContactModel` to display the textbox:

```
@model MVC3App.WebUI.Models.ContactModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { placeholder = "* Name" })
```

The generated HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The field Name: is required." 
       id="ContactModel_Name" 
       name="ContactModel.Name" 
       placeholder="* Name" type="text" value="">
```

When POSTed back to the server the value is not binding to the model properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendPatientContact(ContactModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // model.Name is null. :S

        return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
}
```

If I manually set the `name` of the textbox to `name="Name"`, the value is binding correctly to the model property. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation you should not use `@Html.EditorFor` method but instead use `@{Html.RenderPartial("_ContactPartialView", Model.ContactModel);}`